# from bs4 import BeautifulSoup BeautifulSoup is not accessed

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a Python program that will scrape out information from a website, and to do that, I'm trying to use the BeautifulSoup4 Library.
I have installed it in the terminal, and when I try the `pip freeze` command, it indeed appears to be there.

But when I try to import it into VS Code, the error `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup BeautifulSoup is not accessed` shows up and I don't know how to solve it.

As said above, I've tried to import it into VSCode but got the error, so I tried to pip install it in the terminal only to realize it has already been installed but the problem is still there.

heres how i imported it into VSCode:

```py
    from tkinter import *
    from tkinter.messagebox import *
    import sqlite3
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import hashlib
```

Comment: Add error logs, pip freeze content and your python version to understand your problem better

Comment: This sounds like Pylance reporting that it can't find the package.  Depending on if you installed it to a venv, or as a system wide or user package you may need to configure other source paths for it to check.  https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/blob/main/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#unresolved-import-warnings

Comment: It is NOT Pylance saying that it can't find the package.  It's just saying "you have imported this but you haven't used it yet."  Totally ignorable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error, `"BeautifulSoup" is not accessed Pylance` is a hint, which means that although you have imported `BeautifulSoup`, you have not used it in the code behind, that is, you have not accessed it after importing.

- Prompt warning when not in use

  [image]
- The warning disappears after using

  [image]

This does not affect your execution of the script. If your script has no other errors, running the code can be successful.

There are many ways to solve it:

1. remove the import as you are not using it either

   [image]
2. Add code to use it in the subsequent section
3. Adding following to *settings.json* to eliminate such warnings

   ```
       "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides": {
           "reportUnusedClass": "none",
           "reportUnusedImport": "none",
       },
   ```